# how to operate in a macro parameter before token pasting?

Tags: c, macros

I've a function (ansi c) that is recursive in its definition. Thus, it is in the form:

```
void function_2(int *value){
    /*this is the base function*/
}
void function_4(int *value){
    function_2(value);
    function_2(value);
    /*other operations*/
}
void function_8(int *value){
    function_4(value);
    function_4(value);
    /*other operations*/
}
```

And so on.
To create these functions, I'm creating macros, such as:

```
#define FUNCTION( m, h)\
void function_##m(int *value){\
    function_##h(value);\
    function_##h(value);\
    /*other operations\
};
```

And then I make their declarations as follows:

```
FUNCTION(4,2)
FUNCTION(8,4)
```

Notice that the second macro parameter (h) is always half the value of the first macro parameter (m). Is there any means so I can make the macro using only one parameter (m) and than operate with it so when I concatenate it (using ##) I can use "m/2" instead of h?

It should be something as:

```
function_##m/2(value);\
```

Comment: There is not a non-brute-force solution, unfortunately. Codebases will sometimes contain thousands of macros of the form `#define PP_DIV2_2754 1377` to work around this deficiency.

Comment: Thanks @Sneftel! This is so sad. Well, at least I'll stop to search for it!

Comment: the other solution is to move to C++, which of course allows arithmetic and recursion in template instantiation. Come over to the dark side... if you only knew its power.......

Comment: Why not skip the macros and make `m` a function parameter?

Comment: @Sneftel, I wish I could move to C++! But I'm trapped by a tool which will only run ansi C code...

Comment: @MOehm, I departed from a code where m is a function parameter. However I want a specific function for each m size. Sadly I can't disclosure the code I'm working with to increase the problem understanding...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use compile time calculation and token pasting like what you want to do. On the other hand, if you `/*other operations*/` are same and only the value of `m` is changing, it might be best to make `m` into a parameter instead of using macros to define many functions.

You could make it similar to the following:

```
void function(int m, int *value) {
    if ( m == 2 ) {
        /*run base code*/
    } else {
        function(m/2, value);
        function(m/2, value);
        /*other operations*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I actually departed from a code like this one, but now I'm trying to optimize the code. Such functions are executed billions of times, and are responsible for some good 96% of my program's execution time. They aren't asymptotically complex, however because the large number of executions they require optimizations.

Comment: In that case, you might be stuck to writing a whole bunch of `FUNCTION`s. You could write a script to do that for you though.

Comment: Yep! I'm stuck writing some few FUNCTIONs (their number are not so high). I'm only bending to use the macro definitions because if I write each function by hand, one by one, I'm more prone to make a mistake on the "other operations", that are a little bit tricky.

Comment: That's why I suggested scripting it.

Comment: If your functions are executed billions of times on `int`s, chances are that you often call the functions with the same values. If the functions are pure, i.e. don't rely on external data, you might get something out of memoization.

Comment: The int* in the real program is a pointer to an array of int (in the question the name "value" induces to think about only one value, instead of values) . As in the sample, function_2  would operate over 4 values, function_4 over 16, function_8 over 64 and thus function_n operates over n^2 values. Also, the recursive calls passes specific positions of such an array, instead of passing direct the "value" address.